# Pandas: Duplicated level name: <Column Name>, assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0."

Tags: python, pandas

```
Item              AddDate                     COUNT(Number)
Item 3         2021-01-05                     111
Item 3         2021-01-06                     223
Item 3         2021-01-07                     44
Item 3         2021-01-26                     431
Item 3         2021-01-25                     12
Item 3         2020-12-25                     43
Item 1         2021-01-19                     53
Item 1         2021-01-18                     12
Item 2         2021-04-06                     15
Item 2         2020-11-30                     132
```

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like above (type is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`)

I tried to generate a pivot_table by doing

```
df = df.pivot_table(
                index='AddDate',
                columns=['AddDate', 'Item'],
                values='COUNT(Number)',
                fill_value=0,
                aggfunc=sum)
```

This gives me `Duplicated level name: \"AddDate\", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0."`

I tried changing the `AddDate` column name to something else, but it didn't fix the issue.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is wrongly assigned parameter `columns=['AddDate', 'Item']`, so is used `AddDate` for generate new index values (`index='AddDate'`), but also for `MultiIndex` by `AddDate, Item` combinations (`columns=['AddDate', 'Item']`).

I think you need only `columns='Item'`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(
                index='AddDate',
                columns='Item',
                values='COUNT(Number)',
                fill_value=0,
                aggfunc=sum)
```